# Custom wordpress keyword search by title

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am using a template for a project (unfortunately client's idea), this template has a dropdown search section for the user to search through the custom posts (properties). The only issue is, there is no keywords box for the user to search by keywords.

I am trying to integrate a search function for the user to search via keywords however this is proving a lot more difficult than I first thought. I am not the most proficient with wordpress (I use EE).

Could someone please help me integrate a keyword search function into this following code:

customsearchform.php

```
<form id="search" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/<?php echo $slugname; ?>" method="post">

            <label>Keywords</label>
            <input type="text" name="keywords" style="width:190px;margin-bottom:10px;" />

            <div id="location"> 
            <label><?php echo get_option('wp_location_text')  ?></label>
                <?php
                $location_level1 = get_option('wp_location_level1');
                $arr_location_level1 = explode("\n", $location_level1);

                echo "<select id='location_level1' name='location_level1'>";
                $counter = 0;
                foreach ($arr_location_level1 as $item => $value) {
                    if($counter == 0) {
                    echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>Anywhere</option>";
                    echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
                    } else {

                        echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
                }
                $counter = $counter + 1;
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>



                <?php if(get_option("wp_secondary_location") == 'Enable') { ?>

                     <div id="location_level2_drop_down">
                     <select id="location_level2" name="location_level2">

                     </select>
                     </div>

                <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- end location -->

            <?php if (get_option('wp_rentbuy') == "Show") { ?>
                    <div id="rentorbuy">

                    <label><?php echo get_option('wp_rentorbuy_text') ?></label>
                    <select name="rentbuy">
                        <option value="">Any</option>
                        <option value="rent">Rent</option>
                        <option value="buy">Buy</option>
                    </select>
                    </div><!-- end rentorbuy -->
                <?php } ?>


            <?php

$prices = get_option('wp_price');
$arr_prices = explode("\n", $prices);
foreach ($arr_prices as $price) {
    $priceoptions = $priceoptions . "<option value='" . $price . "'>" . $currencysymbol . number_format($price) . "</option>";
}

$prices2 = get_option('wp_price2');
$arr_prices2 = explode("\n", $prices2);
foreach ($arr_prices2 as $price2) {
    $priceoptions2 = $priceoptions2 . "<option value='" . $price2 . "'>" . $currencysymbol . number_format($price2) . "</option>";
}

?>

            <div id="bedsbathsrow">
            <div id="beds">
                <label><?php echo get_option('wp_bedrooms_text')  ?></label>
                <select name="beds">
                    <option value="">Any</option>
                    <option value="1">1+</option>
                    <option value="2">2+</option>
                    <option value="3">3+</option>
                    <option value="4">4+</option>
                    <option value="5">5+</option>
                </select>
                </div><!-- end beds -->

            <div id="propertytypesection">
            <label><?php echo get_option('wp_propertytype_text')  ?></label>
               <?php
                $propertytype = get_option('wp_propertytype');
                $arr_propertytype = explode("\n", $propertytype);

                $counter = 0;
                echo "<select id='propertytype' name='propertytype'>";

                foreach ($arr_propertytype as $item => $value) {
                    if($counter == 0) {
                    echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>Any</option>";
                    echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
                    } else {

                        echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
                }
                $counter = $counter + 1;
                }   
                echo "</select>";               
                ?>
            </div><!-- end propertytype -->
                </div><!-- end bedsbathsrow -->


            <!-- BUY PRICES -->
            <div id="buyprices">
            <!-- minimum price dropdown menu -->
            <div class="pricemin">
            <label><?php echo get_option('wp_minimumprice_text')  ?></label>
                <select name="minprice_buy">
                    <option value="0">No Min</option>
                    <?php echo $priceoptions ?>
                </select>
            </div><!-- end pricemin -->

            <!-- Maximum price dropdown menu -->
            <div class="pricemax">
            <label><?php echo get_option('wp_maximumprice_text')  ?></label>
                <select name="maxprice_buy">
                    <option value="99999999999999">No Max</option>
                    <?php echo $priceoptions ?>
                </select>
            </div><!-- end pricemax -->
            </div> <!-- end buyprices -->



            <!-- RENT PRICES -->
            <?php if (trim(get_option('wp_rentbuy') == "Show")) { ?>
            <!-- minimum price dropdown menu -->
            <div id="rentprices" style="display: none;">
            <div class="pricemin">
            <label><?php echo get_option('wp_minimumprice_text')  ?></label>
                <select name="minprice_rent">
                    <!-- do not edit the next line -->
                    <option value="0">No Min</option>
                    <?php echo $priceoptions2 ?>
                </select>
            </div><!-- end pricemin -->

            <!-- Maximum price dropdown menu -->
            <div class="pricemax">
            <label><?php echo get_option('wp_maximumprice_text')  ?></label>
                <select name="maxprice_rent">
                    <!-- do not edit the next line -->
                    <option value="9999999999999">No Max</option>
                    <?php echo $priceoptions2 ?>
                </select>
            </div><!-- end pricemax -->
            </div><!-- end RENT PRICES -->
            <?php } ?>



        <div id="propertytyperow">

             <div><input value="<?php echo get_option('wp_searchbutton_text') ?>" type="submit" /></div>

        </div><!-- end propertytyperow -->
        </form>
```

search_query.php

```
<?php 

if (isset($_COOKIE['location_level1']) && $_COOKIE['location_level1'] != '') {

$search_location_level1 = $_COOKIE['location_level1'];
} else {
$search_location_level1 = trim($_POST['location_level1']);
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['location_level2']) && $_COOKIE['location_level2'] != '') {
$search_location_level2 = $_COOKIE['location_level2'];
} else {
$search_location_level2 = trim($_POST['location_level2']);
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['beds']) && $_COOKIE['beds'] != '') {
$search_bedrooms = $_COOKIE['beds'];
} else {
$search_bedrooms = trim($_POST['beds']);
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['baths']) && $_COOKIE['baths'] != '') {
$search_bathrooms = $_COOKIE['baths'];
} else {
$search_bathrooms = trim($_POST['baths']);
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['minprice_buy']) && $_COOKIE['minprice_buy'] != '') {
$search_pricemin_buy = $_COOKIE['minprice_buy'];
} else {
$search_pricemin_buy = '0';
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['maxprice_buy']) && $_COOKIE['maxprice_buy'] != '') {
$search_pricemax_buy = $_COOKIE['maxprice_buy'];
} else {
$search_pricemax_buy = '99999999999999';
}


if (isset($_COOKIE['minprice_rent']) && $_COOKIE['minprice_rent'] != '') {

//echo $_COOKIE['minprice_rent'] . "...";
$search_pricemin_rent = $_COOKIE['minprice_rent'];
} else {
//echo "222";
$search_pricemin_rent = '0';
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['maxprice_rent']) && $_COOKIE['maxprice_rent'] != '') {
$search_pricemax_rent = $_COOKIE['maxprice_rent'];
} else {
$search_pricemax_rent = '99999999999999';
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['propertytype']) && $_COOKIE['propertytype'] != '') {
$search_propertytype = $_COOKIE['propertytype'];
} else {
$search_propertytype = trim($_POST['propertytype']);
}

if (get_option('wp_rentbuy') == "Show") {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['rentbuy']) && $_COOKIE['rentbuy'] != '') {
    $search_buyorrent = $_COOKIE['rentbuy'];
    } else {
    $search_buyorrent = trim($_POST['rentbuy']);
    }
} else {

    $search_buyorrent = '';
}


$checkalllistings = $_GET['alllistings'];
if ($checkalllistings == true) { 

    $search_location_level1 = '';
    $search_location_level2 = '';
    $search_bedrooms = '';
    $search_bathrooms = '';
    $search_pricemin_buy = '0';
    $search_pricemax_buy = '99999999999999';
    $search_pricemin_rent = '0';
    $search_pricemax_rent = '99999999999999';
    $search_propertytype = '';
    $search_buyorrent = '';

}


?>





<?php
$_ids = array();
function getIds( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $searchresults = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
    if ( !empty ($searchresults) ) {
        foreach( $searchresults as $_post ) {
            $tmp[] = $_post['ID'];
        }
    }

    return $tmp;
}




global $wpdb;


//$query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1 WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p.post_type = 'listing' AND p.post_status = 'publish'";
$query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p WHERE p.post_type = 'listing' AND p.post_status = 'publish'";
        $all = getIds( $query );
        $_ids = ( !empty($all) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $all) : $all ) : "" );


if ($search_buyorrent != "") {
        $query = "SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
                WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key = 'rob_value' AND p1.meta_value = '$search_buyorrent'";
        $spm = getIds( $query );

        $_ids = ( !empty($spm) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $spm) : "" ) : "" );
}


if ($search_buyorrent == "buy" || $search_buyorrent == "") {
        $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
                WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='price_value' AND convert(p1.meta_value, signed) BETWEEN '$search_pricemin_buy' AND '$search_pricemax_buy'";
        $spm = getIds( $query );
        $_ids = ( !empty($spm) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $spm) : "" ) : "" );
}


if ($search_buyorrent == "rent") {

        $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
                WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='price_value' AND convert(p1.meta_value, signed) BETWEEN '$search_pricemin_rent' AND '$search_pricemax_rent'";
        $spm = getIds( $query );
        $_ids = ( !empty($spm) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $spm) : "" ) : "" );
}





if($search_location_level1 != '')
{
$search_location_level1 = trim($search_location_level1);

    $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
            WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key = 'location_level1_value' AND p1.meta_value = '$search_location_level1'";
    $sll1 = getIds( $query );

    $_ids = ( !empty($sll1) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $sll1) : "" ) : "" );
} 



if($search_location_level2 != '')
{
$search_location_level2 = trim($search_location_level2);

    $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
            WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='location_level2_value' AND trim(p1.meta_value)='$search_location_level2'";
    $sll2 = getIds( $query );
    $_ids = ( !empty($sll2) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $sll2) : "" ) : "" );
}

if($search_bedrooms != '')
{
    $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
            WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='beds_value' AND p1.meta_value >= '$search_bedrooms'";

    $sbr = getIds( $query );
    $_ids = ( !empty($sbr) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $sbr) : "" ) : "" );
} 



if($search_bathrooms != '')
{
    $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
            WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='baths_value' AND p1.meta_value >='$search_bathrooms'";

    $sbt = getIds( $query );

    $_ids = ( !empty($sbt) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $sbt) : "" ) : "" );
}





if($search_propertytype != '')
{

$search_propertytype = trim($search_propertytype);


    $query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
            WHERE p.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key='propertytype_value' AND p1.meta_value='$search_propertytype'";
    $sptt = getIds( $query );


    $_ids = ( !empty($sptt) ? ( !empty($_ids) ? array_intersect( $_ids, $sptt) : "" ) : "" );
}

?>

<a name="headeranchor"></a>
<?php if ($checkalllistings == true) { 
$alllistings = true;
if (count($_ids) > 3) {
    $results = " (" . count($_ids) . ")"; 
    } else {
    $results = "";
    }

?>

<h2 id="heading_searchresults" class="results"><?php echo get_option('wp_alllistings') . $results; ?></h2>
<?php } else { ?>
<h2 id="heading_searchresults" class="results"><?php echo get_option('wp_searchresults') . $results; ?></h2>
<?php } ?>


<?php
if($resultsorder) {
    //get value from order dropdown on search results page
    $resultsorder = $resultsorder;
    } else {
    $resultsorder = get_option('wp_searchorder');
}

    switch ($resultsorder) {
        case "Price Descending":
            $metakey = 'price_value';
            $order = 'DESC';
            $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
            break;
        case "Price Ascending":
            $metakey = 'price_value';
            $order = 'ASC';
            $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
            break;
        case "Date Descending":
            $metakey = '';
            $order = 'DESC';
            $orderby = 'date';
            break;
        case "Date Ascending":
            $metakey = '';
            $order = 'ASC';
            $orderby = 'date';
            break;
        case "Random":
            $metakey = '';
            $order = '';
            $orderby = 'rand';
            break;
    }




if (!empty($_ids) && !$alllistings) {
    $wpq = array ('post_type' => 'listing', 'meta_key' => $metakey, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, 'post__in' => $_ids,  'post_status' => 'publish', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => get_option('wp_searchresultsperpage') );

} elseif (empty($_ids) && !$alllistings) {

    // $_ids array is empty because search got no results
    // $_ids array will be empty if page is an "All Listings" page. Don't run this code if is All Listings because All Listings will show all listings. This code will display "no results found"
    $wpq = array ('post_type' =>'listing', 'meta_key' => $metakey, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, 'post__in' => array('0'),'post_status' => 'publish', 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => get_option('wp_searchresultsperpage'));
} elseif ($alllistings) {
    // This is an All Listings page, so show all results
    $wpq = array ('post_type' =>'listing', 'paged' => $paged, 'meta_key' => $metakey, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => get_option('wp_searchresultsperpage'));
}
query_posts($wpq);

//$listing = new WP_Query($wpq);

?>


<?php 
if ($search_location_level1 != "") { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#location_level2").load("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/secondary_search_locations/<?php echo $search_location_level1 ?>.txt");
</script>
<?php } ?>



<?php 
if ($search_buyorrent == "buy" || $search_buyorrent == "") { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#buyprices').show();
        $('#rentprices').hide();
</script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#buyprices').hide();
        $('#rentprices').show();
</script>
<?php } ?>





<script type="text/javascript">
function remember( selector ){
$(selector).each(
function(){
//if this item has been cookied, restore it
var name = $(this).attr('name');
if( $.cookie( name ) ){
$(this).val( $.cookie(name) );
}
//assign a change function to the item to cookie it
$(this).change(
function(){
$.cookie(name, $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: 365 });
}
);
}
);
}

<?php 
if ($search_buyorrent == "buy" || $search_buyorrent == "") {  ?>

remember( '[name=minprice_buy], [name=maxprice_buy]' );
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($search_buyorrent == "rent") { ?>
remember( '[name=minprice_rent], [name=maxprice_rent]' );
<?php } ?>
</script>





<?php
/*
echo '<pre>';
print $query;
echo '</pre>';
*/
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been trying all day for this, anyone able to help?